# Data Munging Challenge. How do I join the correct coefficients to the correct observation in a summarized table

Tags: r, data-munging

Before I start, the a basic answer to this question can be found here:
[Correctly binding coefficients to summarized table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668662/correctly-binding-coefficients-to-summarized-table)

This question is different in the fact that I need to correctly join the correct coefficients to the correct position in the summary table based on where a knot is placed.  I use the `I(pmax(0, variable - knot))` technique to place my splines.  The end result is a table of unique values of each variable, a summarized measure and the correct model statistics (see my final (yet unfinished) table in below example code).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

#pull in and gather data
mtcars1 <- as_tibble(mtcars)
mtcars1$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
#run model and produce model-summary table
model <- glm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + I(pmax(0, hp - 100)), data = mtcars1)

model_summary <- tidy(model)

#produce final summary table
summary_table <- mtcars1 %>%
  select(cyl, hp, wt) %>%
  gather(key = variable, level, - wt) %>%
  group_by(variable, level) %>%
  summarise("sum_wt" = sum(wt)) %>%
  mutate(term = paste0(variable, level)) %>%
  left_join(model_summary, by = c("term" = "term"))
```

The challenge is taking the `I(pmax(0, hp -100))` term in the `model_summary` table and correctly join the estimate, std.error, statistic and p.value to each hp observation in the `summary_table` that is <= 100, in addition to joining the other `hp` estimate statistics to the hp observation in the `summary_table` that is > 100.

Comment: Perhaps look at `fuzzyjoin` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fuzzyjoin/versions/0.1.3 defining a custom join function

Comment: `hp` is not a categorical variable that is why the summary will not include summaries for each observation in `hp`. Also, use `full_join` instead of `left_join` since the latter will drop unmatched rows.

Comment: Yes @hpesoj626.  There lies the challenge.  I need to match the correct numerically based coefficient to a categorical observation.  There is a specific visual output required that needs the data this way.  I currently use a proprietary software that does this but advocating for R to replace it.

Comment: Are the estimates predicted values in your use case?

Comment: No I wouldn't say the predicted values. We use the estimates (or the exponent of them) to judge where each level of a variable is relative the others.  If we're happy with them, then it's done, if not, we'll tweek the knots or add/drop variables until we are.

Comment: add the expected output

Comment: Hi @rawr.  The table, `summary_table` produced in the code would be the output, only with the correct coefficients from the `model_summary` table instead of `null` values.

Comment: yeah but you would have two hp? one for `hp` and one for `I(hp)`? Now the summary table has a row for each unique hp, but it also sounds like you want them all filled in with something

Comment: My apologies @rawr.  The I(hp) model stats should go to all hp levels in the `summary_table` that is less or equal to 100.  The rest of the hp should have the hp values in them.  Does that make sense?

Comment: yes but more complicated.. :}